# iOS 7.1 insertRowsAtIndexPaths animation doesn't work

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I'm testing my app on iOS 7.1 and when the following line is executed, the cells disappear for a short period (about a second) and then the new cell with old ones appear without any animation.

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
```

Same thing happens when I remove a cell with animation.

This problem doesn't exist on iOS7. I have tested on both on simulator and device by the way. What could be the problem?

Edit:
I figured out the problem, below you can find the answer.

Comment: @nicael sorry, I was debugging it to see if it behaves the same, I edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

Well the problem was caused by setting the table cell's background: [UIColor clearColor]; I figured out while debugging. Since my tableview's background is a solid color, I assigned that color to background of my cell view, and now the animation works normally and cells don't disappear anymore. However, I have no idea why this happens in iOS 7.1, and not in iOS 7.0.

Comment: This solved my issue too! 
in ios7.1 there are some changes regarding the cell views. Also they changed the cell view clipping  to not clip the contents

Answer (score 1):

It works perfectly)))) You wrote not to use animation: `UITableViewRowAnimationNone`.
Replace it with `UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic`, for example.

Comment: Sorry, I was debugging and I forgot to change, UITableViewRowAnimationBottom should be in instead of UITableViewRowAnimationNone

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the line (with animation as @nicael suggested) between the lines:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];

...

[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Sometimes it makes a difference.